# Why is SFML not able to connect to my keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, sfml

I am using SFML in a C++ app in xcode. I need to recognize keystrokes in the program. I have a macbook pro with Catalina 10.15.2 installed. This is the type of code I need to run:

```
#include <SFML/Window/Keyboard.hpp>

void Camera::move(){
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)){
        pos_x+=step_size;
    }
}
```

Everytime I run the app I get a request to enter my admin credentials to allow the app access to  my keystrokes. After doing so the code still does not recognize any keystrokes. I also get the following messages in my console:

```
2021-02-02 01:46:07.445793+0100 code[24460:2367069] [default] 0x100011151: TCC deny IOHIDDeviceOpen
2021-02-02 01:46:07.446085+0100 code[24460:2367069] [default] 0x100011111: TCC deny IOHIDDeviceOpen
2021-02-02 01:46:07.446150+0100 code[24460:2367069] [default] 0x100011151: TCC deny IOHIDDeviceOpen
We got a keyboard without any keys (1)
2021-02-02 01:46:07.446225+0100 code[24460:2367069] [default] 0x100011111: TCC deny IOHIDDeviceOpen
We got a keyboard without any keys (1)
```

Other than this, the SFML library works flawlessly on my computer. Does anyone have an idea what the issue might be and how I can solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

isKeyPressed polls the hardware and on Catalina, you need to specifically grant the app access to your Mac in Security and Privacy preferences. I don't use mac so this might not work because I am using the macOS user guide to answer this question

Comment: I encountered another piece of software crashing with `TCC deny IOHIDDeviceOpen` in the console, and this was indeed the solution. Normally the OS prompts you, but for some reason this didn't happen.